# Annotate count default to 0 (ZERO) in Django

Tags: python, django

I have the following code in views.py

```
class UserPostListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'blog/user_posts.html'
    context_object_name='posts'
    paginate_by = 4

    def get_queryset(self):
        user = get_object_or_404(User, username=self.kwargs.get('username'))
        return Post.objects.filter(author=user).order_by('-date_posted')

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(UserPostListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        user = get_object_or_404(User, username=self.kwargs.get('username'))
        context['postuser'] = Post.objects.filter(author=user).order_by('-date_posted')[:1]
        context['posts'] = Post.objects.filter(author=user).order_by('-date_posted')
        context['postns'] = {d['status__count'] for d in Post.objects.filter(author=user,status="NOT STARTED").order_by('status').values('status').annotate(Count('status'))}
```

**html**

```
{% for post in postns %}
    <div class="col-auto col-ns-st padding-col-st"><span class="vertical-span"><i class="fa fa-circle color-ico-st"></i>&nbsp;{{ post }}</span></div>
{% endfor %}
```

**models.py**

```
class Post(models.Model):
    NS= 'NOT STARTED'
    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        ('NOT STARTED','NOT STARTED'),
        ('IN PROGRESS','IN PROGRESS'),
        ('COMPLETE','COMPLETE'),
        )
status=models.CharField(max_length=40, choices = STATUS_CHOICES,default=NS)
```

when i have post with the legend "NOT STARTED", the code is working and counting the number of post, but if there are no post, is not showing any value.

How can i make that code default to "0" if no data is posted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you *filter* on the status, it seems to make more sense to use [**`.count()`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#count) here:

```
context['postns'] = Post.objects.filter(
    author=user,status="NOT STARTED"
).count()
```

You can then render this with:

```
<div class="col-auto col-ns-st padding-col-st"><span class="vertical-span"><i class="fa fa-circle color-ico-st"></i>&nbsp;{{ postns }}</span></div>
```

Comment: Hi @willem, this is giving me an error: 'Coalesce' object has no attribute 'default_alias'

Comment: @chrislumber: yes, you need to specify the name of the annotation, since it is no longer a "simple" one like `Count`, etc.

Comment: Hi @willem, i tried that but still not showing "0", actually is not showing the div. I've just write more information in the question.

Comment: @chrislumber: well then you likely *render* it not properly.

Comment: @chrislumber: see queryset at the bottom. Since you filter, it will not anotate anything. You need to use `.count()` at the end.